# Mass Find and Replace - Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, find-and-replace

I am trying to create a macro in order to do a mass find and replace across multiple word documents. I have found this one on the net and altered it however I keep getting a run time error (5174) saying that the file could not be found (even though it is definitely in the folder).

Also after I have found a solution to the initial issue I need to be able to Find and replace pictures which are in a footer.

```
Sub ReplaceText()
  Dim Directory As String
  Dim FType As String
  Dim FName As String

Directory = "C:\Users\pieria\Desktop\TempPics"
FType = "*.docx"

ChDir Directory
FName = Dir(FType)
' for each file you find, run this loop
Do While FName <> ""
    ' open the file
    Documents.Open FileName:=FName  '<--Error is supposedly here 

    ' search and replace the company name
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "CompanyA"
        .MatchCase = True
        .Replacement.Text = "CompanyB"
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    ' save and close the current document
    ActiveDocument.Close wdSaveChanges

    ' look for next matching file
    FName = Dir
Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: I now believe the issue is this: support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/212664 , Having a bit of toruble implementing it into my Macro as simply adding ".docx" after every single Fname doesnt seem to work. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me.  My guess is that you've got a broken input file and/or wonky file name.

Time to start debugging:

In the VBA editor, [set a breakpoint](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm) on the `Documents.Open FileName:=FName` line, and [add a Watch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frice/archive/2005/10/27/485692.aspx) to `Fname`.

Run the code and each time it stops, note the file name it's working on (shown in the "Watches" pane).  Now, when it throws the error out, you'll know which file it is having problems with.

Check that file for corruption, permission problems, and/or general oddness. :)

[image: Break 'n' Watch]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I believe the issue is this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/212664 , although I do not know how to implement this into my code.Simply adding ".docx" after every single Fname doesnt seem to work. Again, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential answer, it is designed to be user friendly:

```
Public Sub MassReplace()

Dim strPath As String
 Dim strFile As String
Dim FType As String
Dim FName As String
Dim strFind As String
 Dim strReplace As String
 Dim WordApp As Object
 Dim WordDoc As Object
```

'The text above defines your objects

```
 strFind = InputBox("Enter Text to find") 

 strReplace = InputBox("Enter replacement Text")
```

' user defines text they want to find and replace using input boxes

```
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then
     strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
      Else
         MsgBox "No folder selected!", vbExclamation
         Exit Sub
        End If
 End With

  If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
     strPath = strPath & "\"
     strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.docx*")
 End If
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

'The block of code above allows the user to select the folder file to search

```
 Do While strFile <> "" 'Do this while strFile is not blank

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Open MS word
    WordApp.Visible = True 'Make word visible
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(strPath & strFile) 'open file in folder
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Range.Select ' select all text

    With WordApp.Selection.Find 'Using the find function allows a search of text
    .Text = strFind 'find "strFind"
    .Replacement.Text = strReplace 'replacement text is "strReplace"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    '.Format = False
    '.MatchCase = False
    '.MatchWholeWord = False
    '.MatchWildcards = False
    '.MatchSoundsLike = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'replace all text

    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close wdSaveChanges 'Close document and save changes

    End With 'End with block



    WordApp.Quit 'Close the word application
    strFile = Dir 'Go back to the directory

   Loop

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

This seems to work well for Word 2016. It allows a user to define their file path and uses input boxes to define text to replace/find. To replace numbers instead of text define strFind and strReplace as integers (or another number type) instead of text. Happy coding!